# How to retrieve ParamConverter into a service

Tags: php, symfony

How to retrieve all my 3 entities (Departement, Category, Advert) declared as annotation via @ParamConverter in my controller directly into my service ?

I tried many stuff, but nothing works properly...

Thanks !

**Controller**

```
  /**
    * @Template("frontend/advertisement/show.html.twig")
    * @ParamConverter("department", options={"mapping": {"slug_department": "department_slug"}})
    * @ParamConverter("category", options={"mapping": {"slug_category": "slug_fr"}})
    * @ParamConverter("advert", options={"mapping": {"slug_advert": "slug"}})
    * @Route(
    *     "/{_locale}/annonces/{slug_department}/{slug_category}/{slug_advert}",
    *     name="advertShow",
    *     requirements={
    *         "_locale": "en|fr"
    *     }
    * )    */
    public function showAction(Request $request, Department $department , Category $category , Advert $advert  )
    {
        return [
            "advert"=>$advert
        ];
    }
```

**Service.yml**

```
 app.breadcrumb:
        class:     AppBundle\Service\Breadcrumb
        arguments: ['@router']
        tags:
            -  { name: twig.extension }
            - { name: request.param_converter, priority: 20 }
```

**Service.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ParamConverterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class Breadcrumb extends \Twig_Extension implements ParamConverterInterface
{

    protected $router; 

    public function __construct(Router $route)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function generate($path)
      {

        return ["Home", "Item 1 ", "Item 2"];
      }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'breadcrumb' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'generate')
        );
    }

    function supports(ParamConverter $configuration)
    {   

    }

    function apply(Request $request, ParamConverter $configuration)
    {
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Breadcrumb';
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have param converters already implemented and working? Do you need objects created by param converter in controller or in `Breadcrumb` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of whole I'd recommend to implement 3 converters and separate them from twig extension. It is going to be too much for one class.

Second. Subscribe your service as event listener to kernel controller event. At this stage the request have all data you need in `$event->getRequest()->attributes`

Comment: I Stepashka ! You solution seems works properly. Many thanks

Comment: If you want more code examples - let me know. I was not sure that it is what you want so made the answer short.

Comment: Whoever put a -1 please explain why.

Answer (score 1):

*Here is my vision on how it could be done (untested!)*

First of all, you should return all the entities from your controller in an associated array.

After that you should implement `Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface` in your service. So that it looks like this:

**Service.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
// .. other imports

class Breadcrumb extends \Twig_Extension implements ParamConverterInterface, EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $entities = array();
    // .. other fields ..

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::VIEW => 'onKernelView',
        );
    }

    public function onKernelView(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event)
    {
        $view = $event->getControllerResult();
        if (is_array($view) && array_key_exists('entities', $view)) {
            $this->entities = $view;
        }
    }

    // .. other methods ..
}
```

**Service.yml**

```
app.breadcrumb:
    class:     AppBundle\Service\Breadcrumb
    arguments: ['@router']
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
        - { name: request.param_converter, priority: 20 }
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.view, method: onKernelView, priority: 101 }
```